# Equivalent class for Publishallxmlrequest of crm 4.0 in crm 2013 xrm sdk

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I am migrating my code crm 4.0 code to crm 2013 using xrm sdk.

But I am not able to locate PublishAllXMLRequst Class in xrm sdk.

If anyone know kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `PublishAllXmlRequest` is the same in CRM 2013:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.publishallxmlrequest.aspx

Make sure that you added the `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages` namespace

Comment: Hello Sir, I would like to know how we will customize listmember entity ribbon button on account Associated view...? If you have any idea kindly help me.?   e.g. Marketing List -> Marketing List Members ->  and we found assoicated view subgrid.